# Growing Array of Pointers ERROR: Incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm working on an assignment and I have this error which makes no sense to me. Basically we have the class "Playlist" which has an array of pointers to "Track"s

```
class Playlist{
private:
    string playlistName;
    int trackCount;
    Track*  tracks[0];
public:
    Playlist(string name);
    Track* GetTrack(int index);
    int GetTrackCount();
    void AddTrack(Track* track, int index);
    void AddTrack(Track* track);
    void RemoveTrack(int index);
    void RemoveTrack(Track* track);
};
```

The error is occurring in the functions AddTrack(Track t,int i) and RemoveTrack(int i)

```
    Playlist.cpp: In member function ‘void Playlist::AddTrack(Track*, int)’:
Playlist.cpp:27:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Track* [(((Playlist*)this)->Playlist::trackCount + 1)]’ to ‘Track* [1]’
     tracks= newtracks;
           ^
Playlist.cpp: In member function ‘void Playlist::RemoveTrack(int)’:
Playlist.cpp:42:12: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Track* [(((Playlist*)this)->Playlist::trackCount + -1)]’ to ‘Track* [1]’
     tracks = newtracks;
            ^
student@ldnel:~/Documents/A2$ g++ -std=c++14 *.cpp
Playlist.cpp: In member function ‘void Playlist::AddTrack(Track*, int)’:
Playlist.cpp:28:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Track* [newSize]’ to ‘Track* [1]’
     tracks= newtracks;
           ^
Playlist.cpp: In member function ‘void Playlist::RemoveTrack(int)’:
Playlist.cpp:44:12: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Track* [newSize]’ to ‘Track* [1]’
     tracks = newtracks;
            ^
```

Here's my function implementations:

```
Playlist::Playlist(string name){
    playlistName=name;
}
Track* Playlist::GetTrack(int index){

    return tracks[index];
}
int Playlist::GetTrackCount(){
    return trackCount;
}
void Playlist::AddTrack(Track* track, int index){
    int newSize = trackCount+1;
    Track  *newtracks[newSize];
    for(int i=0;i<newSize;i++){
        if(i<index){
            newtracks[i] = tracks[i];
        }else if(i==index){
            newtracks[i]=track;
        }else{
            newtracks[i]=tracks[i-1];
        }
    }
    tracks= newtracks;
    trackCount++;
}
void Playlist::AddTrack(Track* track){
    AddTrack(track,trackCount);
}
void Playlist::RemoveTrack(int index){
    int newSize = trackCount-1;
    Track *newtracks[newSize];
    for(int i=0;i<newSize;i++){
        if(i<index){
            newtracks[i]=tracks[i];
        }else{
            newtracks[i]=tracks[i+1];
        }
    }
    tracks = newtracks;
    trackCount--;
}
void Playlist::RemoveTrack(Track* track){
    for(int i=0;i<trackCount;i++){
        if(tracks[i]==track){
            RemoveTrack(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I plan on doing is having a Data Manager class that dynamically stores all Tracks and playlists would have a refernce to the tracks it includes. I do not know why it considers the two arrays of different types

Comment: 1. `std::vector` 2. ??? 3. profit.

Comment: @Quentin I'm looking at the vector reference, I can't figure out how to insert at an index, can you tell me what's the prototype for inserting at an index?

Comment: `Track*  tracks[0];` creates an array of `Track` pointers of length 0. Is that really what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign an array of the length x to an array of a different size. I suggest you use std::vector(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array.

You might also want to consider using a std::shared pointer (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

You might also need to take a look at iterators (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) for your AddTrack(Track * track, int index) function.

I would implement it like this:

```
class Playlist {
private:
    std::string playlistName;
    int trackCount;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Track>> tracks;
public:
    Playlist(std::string name);
    std::shared_ptr<Track> GetTrack(int index);
    int GetTrackCount();
    void AddTrack(std::shared_ptr<Track> track, int index);
    void AddTrack(std::shared_ptr<Track> track);
    void RemoveTrack(int index);
    void RemoveTrack(std::shared_ptr<Track> track);
};
```

Here would be my add functions:

```
void Playlist::AddTrack(std::shared_ptr<Track> track, int index) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Track>>::iterator itor = tracks.begin();
    itor += index;
    tracks.insert(itor, track);
}
void Playlist::AddTrack(std::shared_ptr<Track> track) {
    tracks.push_back(track);
}
```

I am confident you can implement the rest on your own. :)